# Does Malwarebytes have a sleep mode?

Tags: windows-7, anti-malware

A couple of days ago I started running Malwarebytes on my wife's PC.  Finally, this morning I stopped it from running, after it had run for a little over 44 hours.  That seems **way** longer than I've ever seen Malwarebytes run on any Windows machine.  I'm wondering if Malwarebytes has something like a sleep mode?  My wife would minimize it and leave it running like that overnight.

Comment: By "run it" do you mean having it running in the background or actively scanning?

Comment: I mean having it running in the background, most likely at a low priority.

Comment: Then I don't understand what the problem is. It is designed to run in the background. If you have a key, then it will scan files on access and warn you about bad ones; if you don't have a key, then it just sits there for "convenient" access. Until you specifically exit it, it will stay there, it does not spontaneously exit on its own.

Comment: The problem is we only run it in an on demand basis.  So, it doesn't makes sense to me at it would take 44+ hours to run, that's all.

Comment: It's *not* "taking 44 hours to run". When you start the program, it loads and stays loaded with a tray icon. If you have purchased a key, then you can enable the on-access scanner, but if you are using the free version, it does nothing and just sits there waiting for you to click the icon to run a manual scan. It will stay there forever or until you [right-click the tray icon and select Exit](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CHWiw.png) or reboot.